# How to implement protocol method for the UIApplicationDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working in a class, call it Module, and I need to implement this method in the AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
   ...
}
```

I know which class is the AppDelegate (call it App), but I do not have access to edit that class. How can I implement the delegate method from my Module?

I thought about using a category to extend App but this line in the [category docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) is a concern:

*"you’ll need to import the category header file in any source code file where you wish to use the additional methods, otherwise you’ll run into compiler warnings and errors."*

The question is, how can I implement the protocol method in my module in a way so that iOS knows to call my protocol method at the appropriate time?

Comment: That question is about CALLING a method, but I am asking about IMPLEMENTING a method of the UIApplicationDelegate protocol.

Comment: Note - my first comment responds to someone who marked this as a possible duplicate and commented, then deleted those.

Comment: Do you want to implement - (BOOL) application .... from another class?

Comment: Doesn't have to be from another class, but has to be in code I control (I can't edit App). I wrote a category for the App class, but I don't think the protocol method is getting called.

Comment: Ok... Maybe a solution is implement the function and set it in runtime.

Comment: whats the problem? using category is the correct solution. you won't have any compiler warnings/errors in this case

Comment: Have you tested the category? I think that the category method will be getting called, because you need import the category header in your AppDelegate, do you?

Comment: I can't edit anything outside my module - so I can't import my category where I'm instantiating the AppDelegate class. That's why the statement from docs makes me think it won't work.

Comment: It won't work because the header category need to be import in the class that CALL the method. And you don't have access, because is a system class. 
With my answer you can change the implementation of the application delegate in runtime, I tested that with the protocol: applicationDidEnterBackground and it work.

Comment: category works because it added the method to the class. header is only required to call it. no. actually it is not required because you are implementing a protocol. i still cannot understand how category won't work. can you try it and post the error message?

Comment: You are in the correct Bryan, the problem with the category is the same with my approach when the method isn't in the AppDelegate in the first place. Do you know how the OS is managing that?

Answer (score 1):

Ok Joe... If you want to IMPLEMENT the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` from another module, you can do it in runtime.

WE NEED TO ASSUME THAT THE AppDelegate HAVE TEH METHOD IMPLEMENTED

First you need to import the class:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

Then the you need to declare the struct of an object method:

```
struct objc_method {
    SEL method_name;
    char *method_types;
    IMP method_imp;
};
```

And finally you can change the implementation whit this:

```
//Create the selector of the method.
    NSString * openURL = @"application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:";
    SEL selectorOpenURL = NSSelectorFromString(openURL);

    //Get the method of the intance.
    Method openURLMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] class], selectorOpenURL);

    //Get the current implementation.
    IMP openURLIMP = openURLMethod->method_imp;

    //Create your own implementation.
    IMP myOpenURLIMP = imp_implementationWithBlock(^BOOL(id _s, UIApplication * app,NSURL *url,NSString *sourceApplication,id annotation) {

        //Call the original implementation.
        openURLIMP(_s,selectorOpenURL,app,url,sourceApplication,annotation);

        //Here your implementation code.
        NSLog(@"Handling the URL");

        return YES;
    });
```

BUT BE CAREFUL. If you look in my code, I'm calling the original implementation inside my implementation, so if I execute the code to change the implementation more than one, my implementation will be an **inception** (Like the film, my implementation inside my implementation, inside my implementation, inside my implementation and so on).

EDIT:

There is way to add your implementation to the class:

If `class_getInstanceMethod` return null you can alloc the memory for the method and add it to the class later:

```
//If the method dont exist. We need to create one.
    if (!openURLMethod) {
        existMethod = NO;
        openURLMethod = malloc(sizeof(struct objc_method));
        openURLMethod->method_types = "c24@0:4@8@12@16@20";
        openURLMethod->method_name = selectorOpenURL;
    }
```

Adding the method to the class:

```
if (!existMethod) {
        class_addMethod([[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] class], openURLMethod->method_name, openURLMethod->method_imp, openURLMethod->method_types);
    }
```

But the problem is, I suppose, that the Operative System are registering the method when the app start, so if when the app start the method don't exist the OS never will call your method.

I will research about how the OS are management that events. With the `applicationDidEnterBackground`, if you don't have the implementation on the AppDelegate and you add it in runtime, the OS never call your implementation. This is why I assume that the operating system is registering the events when the application starts.

Comment: I like it! This is a very tricky way to implement the protocol method after the fact. But, I'm afraid that I can't assume that the method was implemented in the original AppDelegate. How can I use runtime to implement a method that wasn't originally there?

Comment: Joe, you can see my edit.. But the problem is that the OS don't call the method, I assume the SO is registering the event when the app start. Let me research about that.

Comment: @Bryan thanks for reminding me of method swizzling - I remembered reading about it way back but did not remember the name.

Comment: Wow!! @BryanChen and Joe, I didn't know about swizzling method.

Comment: @dcorbatta Your (updated) technique claims to be able to add a method to a class that didn't already implement that method. JRSwizzle doesn't do that :)

Comment: it can be done using method swizzle + category with more clean code. if you want to add method, use category. if you want to replace method, use method swizzle

Comment: I tried to use a category with my approach, but I have the same problem, the method isn't getting called.

Comment: @Bryan I know that to add method we need to use a category, the problem here is that the method is not called. Do you know how the OS manage that?

Comment: ok i see you real problem. I don't know how system frameworks but from my experience, it is possible that these method are added too late or not added. use `-ObjC` linker flag to make sure it is added if you are using category. add method in `+load` if you are using ObjC api to added method.

Comment: Mmm. I had forgotten the linker flag -ObjC, and the method +load. But I tried it. And it didn't work... :(
Now I have to sleep. @JoeBeuckman if you found the solution please let me know, you too Bryan, I didn't need that, but it is interesting to know how to solve this problem.